# Platform-agnostic bluetooth device identification mechanism

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to write a cross-platform abstraction over Bluetooth. When it comes to identifying devices (or peripherals, as iOS calls them), I'm a bit stumped.

iOS includes an `identifier` property, which is a generated ID assigned to a device the first time it connects. However, Android does not seem to have an equivalent concept. The best I seem to be able to do is to use `BluetoothDevice.getAddress`, which returns a MAC address. I can then turn that into a UUID by doing some byte twiddling.

Is there anything better I can do here to uniquely identify devices in an agnostic manner?

Comment: since iOS and Android do not report a consistent identifier I don't believe that there is any option for you that will provide a cross-platform identifier

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, you cannot use the `identifier` property to identify a device on iOS.

The correct way to do this is to advertise a service with a characteristic's value you can control on device A and discover this on the device B.

Depending on what you want to achieve, there are also SDKs you can use for device discovery, for example newaer, [p2pkit](http://p2pkit.io) or google nearby just to name a few.

Disclaimer: I work for Uepaa, developing p2pkit.io for Android and iOS.